# Mapping SMB Shared folder - Mac to Windows

Tags: windows-10, networking, macos, network-shares, smb

Have set up a SMB shared folder on a Mac over a LAN. So my Mac is the host

I want to simply enable this shared folder to always auto mount when I reboot -login on my Windows machine.

I assume this means using 'Map Network Drive'.

Should be simple enough however when I browse to a folder from Map Network Drive all I see is Network, not my shared folder.
Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: In my experience it means the drive isn't accessible to your Windows user.

Comment: Please try to insert \\IP of SMB server\shared folder or insert \\hostname of SMB server\shared folder in Folder blank.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered through trial and error:
you need to add full path. Shared drive and folder

```
//<path to share drive>/<path to shared folder>
```

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean; can you be more detailed?  … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.